# Radio&Checkbox buttons Contact form 7 not clickable

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

This is the code in documentation:

```
[checkbox* your-country use_label_element "China" "India" "San Marino"]

[radio your-sports label_first default:2 "Football" "Tennis" "Pole-vault"]
```

But the `radio` and `checkboxes` are not clickable in my code. What am I missing here?

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
[radio customRadio id:customRadio1 class:custom-control-input "value4"]
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Something</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
[radio customRadio id:customRadio2 class:custom-control-input "value5"]
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2">Something</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
[checkbox checkbox1 id:customCheck1 class:custom-control-input "Value1"] 
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Something</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
[checkbox checkbox2 id:customCheck2 class:custom-control-input "value2"]
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Something</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the documentation you have mentioned? Welcome, by the way.

Comment: It's the official documentation https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/

Comment: Inspect element:                                                                                                                         
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox custom-control-input" id="customCheck2"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" value="value2"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">value2</span></label></span></span>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">J</label>
 </div>

Comment: I'am adding a label tag with it's own class and I want it like that but the label tag doesn't show up on span tags and when I use use_label_element I guess you can't add a class to it this way

Comment: first check any other div is overlapping your checkbox and radio

Comment: @charankumar I think the <label> tag,has the class custom-control-label and is adding a design to the button and that button is not getting the input.INSECT ELEMNT            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox custom-control-input" id="customCheck2"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" value="value2"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">value2</span></span></span> <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">J</label> </div>

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

[radio radio-264 use_label_element default:1 "value4 Something" "value5 Something"]
[checkbox checkbox-430 use_label_element "Value1 Something" "Value2 Something"]

Comment: I think the label tag is causing my error because it has a class and is customizing the input button so that button is not being clicked.This is from inspect element result:                    
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox custom-control-input" id="customCheck2"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2[]" value="value2"><span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">value2</span></span></span>
<label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">J</label>
 </div>